# Regex data annotation validation not working

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to use the "RegularExpression" DataAnnotation validaiton in my model. My problem is even for the valid input I provide for the field containing the validation, the regex doesn't match and it fails. 
I try to test the same valid input with the regex in a stand-alone console app and I find it gets through.

My point is, when regex is being used in dataannotation as validation, it considers all input as bad input. What am I missing here?

My regex is for checking comma-seperated email IDs. Here is my model:

```
 public partial class BuildModel 
{
    public Int64 ConfigID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a stream!")]
    public String Name{ get; set; }



    [RegularExpression(@"^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*(;|,)\s*|\s*$))", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email IDs separated by commas")]
    public string EmailIDs { get; set; }

   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The "Required" data-annotation validation works just fine. It is just the Regex one, that won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you just have problem within your Regex.

To validate emails separated by comma you can use this regex:

```
^( *[\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}( *, *)? *)+$
```

[Check in in here](https://regex101.com/r/GTb1ED/2).

Comment: Turns out this works in my app! I'm still not sure why the original regex would work in a console app but not in my app. Also, the rege that you've provided doesn't allow spaces at the start of each of the e-mail IDs. I need a regex to allow valid  comma separated e-mail IDs (and allow spaces at the start or end of the mail IDs!!)

Comment: @Ponni i updated regex ant link to allow spaces. About your console app you should show how you use it there. MVC validation uses `Regex.IsMatch` method under the hood.

Comment: Thank you. However, this forces my string to have a space after the comma. It needs to be optional. Spaces may/may not be present.

Comment: @Ponni it works in both cases. With or without spaces before and after comma

Answer (score 1):

You must the **jquery.validate.min.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js** in your page without these libraries required annotation would not works.

Comment: yes, they are included, which is why the "Required" validations seems to work. It is just the "Regex" validation that I cannot get to work for some weird reason.

Comment: Use the built-en  [EmailAddress] attribute, that will works fine.

Comment: Thanks. These were loading for me in dev, but not in production.